# Android Pixate FreeStyle change default.css path

Tags: android, css, path, pixate

I am using Pixate for skinning android app via CSS, and in their docs it states that default.css file should be placed in assets folder inside app (included in build) and this way everything works fine, but I have to download at the startup this css from some portal and copy it in the application storage directory, can't include it in the assets folder so Pixate doesn't know the new path for this css file.

Is there any way that I can set path to default.css file so that Pixate can know where to look for the css? This path in my case has to be somewhere in external app storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stylesheet is loaded at https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-android/blob/master/pixate-freestyle/src/com/pixate/freestyle/styling/PXStylesheet.java#L88
You can fork and change this to anything you like.
This method is eventually called once via the the `PixateFreestyle.init()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Now, there is a second `init()` method. You can specify your own CSS file, see:

[PixateFreestyle.init(Context context, String cssFileName)](https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-android/blob/master/pixate-freestyle/src/com/pixate/freestyle/PixateFreestyle.java#L130)